# Exponential growth in big-o notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have got problem about understanding the following question. It says:

> Prove that exponential functions have different orders of growth for different
>   values of base.

It looks to me like for example, consider a<sup>n</sup>. If a=3, its growth rate will be larger than when a=2. It looks obvious. Is that really what the question wants? How can i do a formal proof for that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the process for a formal proof? If so, there should be a couple of existing theorems that could help. Also, plotting a graph is **not** a proof, it is visually representing a single instance of this inquiry.

Comment: You could start out by stating both `A` and `B`are positive real numbers that satisfy the condition `A > B`. This implies take a positive real number `C` and multiply it by both sides, so `A*C > B*C`. This is true for all `C`, just make `C=A` and `A*A > B*A`. Since, `A>B`, this necessitates that `A^2 > B^2`and thus have different growth rates. This is not a flawless proof. I would have to spend more time on it to really flesh it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n.

Let 1>a>b without loss of generality, and suppose b^n ∈ O(a^n). This implies that there are positive constants c and k such that 0 ≤ b^n ≤ c.a^n for all n ≥ k, which is impossible :
b^n ≤ c.a^n for all n ≥ k implies (b/a)^n ≤ c  for all n ≥ k
which is in contradiction with lim (b/a)^n = +inf because b/a>1.

If 1>a>b then b^n ∉ O(a^n), but a^n ∈ O(b^n) so O(a^n)⊊O(b^n)