# Big-O with positive constants

Tags: big-o

In this Big-O / Computational Complexity problem
given that a and b are positive constants greater than 1 and n is a variable parameter.

I assumed that a<sup>n+1</sup> = O(a<sup>n</sup>) , a<sup>bn</sup> = O(a<sup>n</sup>)  & a<sup>n+b</sup> = O(a<sup>n</sup>)

First I need to know if I am correct in assuming this.

If so, how would I prove that f(n) = O(f(n)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of big-O:

> f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n.

Let g=f, c=1 and k=0, then you have a trivial demonstration of f(n) ∈ O(f(n))

Similarly, from a<sup>n+1</sup>=a⋅a<sup>n</sup>, let f(n)=a<sup>n+1</sup>, g(n)=a<sup>n</sup>, c=a, k=0, again the proof of O(a<sup>n+1</sup>)=O(a<sup>n</sup>) is trivial. The proof for O(a<sup>n+b</sup>)=O(a<sup>n</sup>) is identical.
O(a<sup>bn</sup>) is not equal to O(a<sup>n</sup>) with a,b>1, see [Exponential growth in big-o notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041273/exponential-growth-in-big-o-notation)